# Cmake add library to a custom gcc compiler

Tags: c, linux, gcc, embedded-linux

I'm trying to compile a small program written in c with additional libraries zlib and libpng for an arm processor using using gcc-linaro-arm-linux.

In some .c file:

```
#include <bzlib.h>
```

If I compile with an ordinary gcc, everything is working fine, but with a gcc-linaro-arm-linux compiler it could not find libraries:

cmake:

```
$cmake -D CMAKE_C_COMPILER="${HOME}/opt/gcc-linaro-arm-linux-gnueabihf-4.8-2014.03_linux/bin/arm-linux-gnueabihf-gcc" -D CMAKE_CXX_COMPILER="${HOME}/opt/gcc-linaro-arm-linux-gnueabihf-4.8-2014.03_linux/bin/arm-linux-gnueabihf-g++" CMakeLists.txt

-- The C compiler identification is GNU 4.8.3
-- The CXX compiler identification is GNU 4.8.3
-- Check for working C compiler: /home/alex/opt/gcc-linaro-arm-linux-gnueabihf-4.8-2014.03_linux/bin/arm-linux-gnueabihf-gcc
-- Check for working C compiler: /home/alex/opt/gcc-linaro-arm-linux-gnueabihf-4.8-2014.03_linux/bin/arm-linux-gnueabihf-gcc -- works
-- Detecting C compiler ABI info
-- Detecting C compiler ABI info - done
-- Check for working CXX compiler: /home/alex/opt/gcc-linaro-arm-linux-gnueabihf-4.8-2014.03_linux/bin/arm-linux-gnueabihf-g++
-- Check for working CXX compiler: /home/alex/opt/gcc-linaro-arm-linux-gnueabihf-4.8-2014.03_linux/bin/arm-linux-gnueabihf-g++ -- works
-- Detecting CXX compiler ABI info
-- Detecting CXX compiler ABI info - done
-- Could NOT find ZLIB (missing:  ZLIB_LIBRARY) (found version "1.2.8")
CMake Error at /usr/share/cmake-2.8/Modules/FindPackageHandleStandardArgs.cmake:108 (message):
  Could NOT find PNG (missing: PNG_LIBRARY PNG_PNG_INCLUDE_DIR)
Call Stack (most recent call first):
  /usr/share/cmake-2.8/Modules/FindPackageHandleStandardArgs.cmake:315 (_FPHSA_FAILURE_MESSAGE)
  /usr/share/cmake-2.8/Modules/FindPNG.cmake:105 (find_package_handle_standard_args)
  src/CMakeLists.txt:3 (find_package)
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to tell CMake where to find your target sysroot. Check out CMAKE_FIND_ROOT_PATH.